# How do you use the routes inside a react Link set inside an Ant Design List?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, antd, ant-design-pro

I'm trying to use Ant Design List with a Link to another page inside the List item:

```
<List
            itemLayout="horizontal"
            dataSource={users}
            // renderItem={users.map(user => (
            renderItem={item => (
              <List.Item key={item.uid}>
                <List.Item.Meta
                  title={item.name}
                  description={item.organisation}
                />
                  {item.email}
                  {<Link
                    to={{
                      pathname: `${ROUTES.USEROVERVIEW}/${item.uid}`,
                      state: { item },
                    }}
                    style={{ float:"right"}}
                  >
                    More
                  </Link>
                  }
              </List.Item>
            // )
          )}
          />
```

The link path set out above works properly if I use it inside a  css pattern that does not use Ant Design.

I have defined a route like this:

```
export const USEROVERVIEW = '/userDetails/:id';
```

When I try to follow the Link inside the List.Item, it inserts an extra */:id* in between the userDetails and the uid that firebase creates.

If I navigate to the pathname specified (ie: userDetails/1) I can render the page, but currently, clicking on the Link in the List.Item sends me to userDetails/:id/1.

How do I get the Ant Design List Item to follow the path name I specified in the Link?

Comment: What is the value in `ROUTES.USEROVERVIEW`?

Comment: It is defined in my routes file as export const USEROVERVIEW = '/userDetails/:id';  so without an :id extension in the path it receives, it doesn't work

Comment: If you define it with `/userDetails/:id`, then isn't it obvious that the link contains it? You need to route to `/userDetails/userId` only (without the `:id` part)

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't understand what you mean. I give the const in the route a 2 part domain extension and then in the view, I give it the two parts I'm looking to display. Somehow, :id is being inserted in between the 2

Comment: If you mean to remove /:id from the const that defines the route - I tried it - it doesn't work.

Comment: Not to remove /:id from the route, remove /:id from the link. Link does not require it, but the route does, you cannot use the same constant for both

Comment: I tried this suggestion. It doesn't work. The url renders: http://localhost:3000/userDetails/:id -- it should be replacing :id with the actual uid

Comment: The link *does not* replace `:id` in the URL, you are not supposed to give it the `:id` in the first place, just what you want it to route to

Comment: So how would I figure out how to do that? The key is the uid?

Comment: The link should be `/userDetails/${item.uid}`, that's it

Comment: Thank you - that worked. I mustn't be able to work with defined routes in Ant Design